# Magento 2- Show Discount percentage in product view page

Tags: magento2, discount, sale-price

I have set the discount in percentage but its showing only for the simple products.Also I want to show it in the configurable products.

For the Simple Products:
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\default.phtml

Answer (score 0):

try to set it also for

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

Comment: Not Working.. Here is the code that we used

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
    $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();    
    $today = time();
    $price = $_product->getPrice();
    if($price){
        $sale = round((($price-$specialprice)/$price)*100);
    }
    if ($specialprice) {
        if ($today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)) { ?>
            <div class="label-product label-sale">
                <span class="sale-product-icon">
                    <?php if($sale) { echo $sale.'%'; } else {echo __('Sale');} ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```